# drupal image field the image doesn't show?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My drupal site has a content type called Published which has a image field.When I migrate the site from Win2003 server to  CentOS , all the Published node's image field doesn't show. It jsut show the
image name as a link, (sorry i can not post images)

[the image shows like this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142185/drupal-image-field-the-image-doesnt-show)

when I click the image name the picture shows in a now tab.

I had do some google,but no result . someone said the directory sitename/default/files should be set 777

but it is 777.

Any suggestions Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Security and Permission in your server
set the CHMOD to 777

https://superuser.com/questions/649765/change-etc-var-permissions-to-777